# Equivalent of a Swift Public method in Objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have the following type of code in one of my Swift Files:

```
public func RMDTestOne(_ value: @autoclosure (), details: String -> Bool) {
    // Call some Private Method.
}
```

I want to move this away from my Swift file into my Objective-C file. This method was firstly added since `RMDTestOne` was a macro `#define` in my Objective-C file and could not be used by Swift. I'm trying to get rid of this wrapping now.

Edit:

To be clearer, the following macro is present is my Objective-C code:

```
#define RMD_TEST_ONE(__value, __details ...) \
({
    // Call some Private Method
})
```

I tried to access this define in my Swift files, however, I was not able to compile any code referencing it. All imports etc. were correct and it turns out that this macro wasn't present at all in the converted files. I was finally able to add the file on adding the `RMDTestOne` method above to a wrapper file. I feel like this file is some unnecessary fluff and wish to remove it. Is there any way by which I could expose this macro in my Objective-C file itself?

Comment: Update your question with your attempted Objective-C code. Clearly explain what issues you are having.

Comment: In Objective-C every method declared in the header file is public.

Comment: Apologies. I've updated the question to make it more clear. Is any more clarification required?

Comment: @vadian - It might be because of the variadic parameters that the method isn't added?

Comment: Change the macro to a public method whose implementation makes the private call.

Answer (score 0):

In objective-c, anything in the .h (header file) is public by default. Conversely, if you want a private method you can just leave off the prototype entirely.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the macro should be available already?

Comment: It should if it's in the .h. Why are you using a macro? I don't know the size and complexity of your codebase, but macros can be dangerous. They are collision prone, like using a program-wide constant.

Comment: Consider any macro such as this: `#define FooIsNil(__a1, __description, ...) ({ ....)}`

Will this be shown in the Swift file?

Comment: I'm sorry I must have misread what you're trying to do. You can't use an objective-c macro in swift. Just change it to a method.